# Is there a way to hide the Primefaces fileUpload progress bar and buttons in advanced mode and auto mode?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Is there a way to hide the Primefaces fileUpload progress bar and buttons in advanced mode and auto mode?

Here is the code that I am using:

```
<p:fileUpload id="scriptUpload" 
                        widgetVar="importDevicesWidget" 
                        fileUploadListener="#{scriptUploadBean.handleFileUpload}"
                        auto="true"
                        label="Choose.."
                        mode="advanced" 
                        update=":infoMessages"
                        sizeLimit="8192" 
                        allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(txt)$/"
                        onstart="clearInvalidFileMsg();$('#progress').show();"
                        oncomplete="clearInvalidFileMsg();$('#progress').hide();importDevicesDialogWidget.hide()"/>
```

The problem is that it makes no sense for the buttons that appear next to the progress bar for each file to be there as the mode is auto so the upload already started!

Here is a screen shot:

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the 3.4 documentation `.ui-fileupload .start`, `.ui-fileupload .cancel` and `.ui-fileupload .progress` selects your fileuploads' start, cancel and progress bar:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .ui-fileupload .start {
        display: none;
    }
    .ui-fileupload .cancel {
        display: none;
    }
    .ui-fileupload .progress {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

For **PrimeFaces 5** this is probably a solution (using it atm)

```
.fileupload-simple > .ui-fileupload-content {
    display: none;
}
.fileupload-simple > .ui-fileupload-buttonbar {
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Then use `fileupload-simple` class in your `fileUpload` component and you're good to go :)

Comment: This depend on the mode though - for example, using mode="advance", the class would be ,fileupload-files

Answer (score 2):

work for me. Primefaces 6.0.1

```
 <style type="text/css">
    .ui-fileupload-content .ui-progressbar {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    margin: 0
    }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I love it when I can answer my own question:

Here is the updated code:

```
<p:dialog appendToBody="true" id="importDevices" widgetVar="importDevicesDialogWidget" header="Import Devices" resizable="false" modal="true" onShow="centerDialog('#importDevicesDialog');">
            <h:form id="importDevicesForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="5">
                    <p:fileUpload id="scriptUpload" 
                        widgetVar="importDevicesWidget" 
                        fileUploadListener="#{scriptUploadBean.handleFileUpload}"
                        auto="true"
                        label="Choose.."
                        mode="advanced" 
                        update=":infoMessages"
                        sizeLimit="8192" 
                        allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(txt)$/"
                        onstart="clearInvalidFileMsg();$('#progress').show();"
                        oncomplete="clearInvalidFileMsg();$('#progress').hide();importDevicesDialogWidget.hide()"/> 
                    <p:spacer height="10px;"/>
                    <p:commandButton value="Cancel" action="javascript.void(0);" onclick="clearInvalidFileMsg();importDevicesDialogWidget.hide();"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
             </h:form>
        </p:dialog>
```

And here is the updated function that hides the progressbar and buttons and also clears out the errors:

```
function clearInvalidFileMsg(){
                if ($("#importDevicesForm").is(':visible')){
                    importDevicesWidget.uploadContent.find("tr.ui-state-error").remove();
                    importDevicesWidget.uploadContent.find("td.progress").remove();
                    importDevicesWidget.uploadContent.find("td.start").remove();
                    importDevicesWidget.uploadContent.find("td.cancel").remove();                        
                }
            }
```

Comment: well, there is a clean css solution for your problem which avoids unnecessary pollution of your backend code with styling stuff.

Comment: @akoskm, please share it here

Comment: @kolossus sure, see my solution above

Answer (score -1):

Using showButtons="false" in fileUpload tag.

Eg:

```html
 <p:fileUpload id="fileUpload" mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="false" update="@form" sizeLimit="100000"  fileLimit="3" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(xlsx|xls)$/"  multiple="false" label="Select File" showButtons="false"/>
```

Comment: There is no such property in current version of PrimeFaces.